# jqtouch... where to start

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am looking for a decent documentation about JQTouch, but I can't find anything structured. Can you help me?

First I am using tag `<li>`, class *Arrow*. When someone swipe left, I need to hide the arrow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a lot from this book:

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/

This is the free version but they also have published it and there's an iPhone app version of it as well.    Good book IMO for the price.